# Regular expression for substitution of similar pattern in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to use a regular expression to detect and substitute some phrases. These phrases follow the
same pattern but deviate at some points. All the phrases are in the same string.

For instance I have this string:

```
/this/is//an example of what I want /to///do
```

I want to catch all the words inside and including the // and substitute them with "".

To solve this, I used the following code:

```
import re
txt = "/this/is//an example of what i want /to///do"
re.search("/.*/",txt1, re.VERBOSE)
pattern1 = r"/.*?/\w+"
a = re.sub(pattern1,"",txt)
```

The result is:

```
' example of what i want '
```

which is what I want, that is, to substitute the phrases within // with "". But when I run the same pattern on the following sentence

```
"/this/is//an example of what i want to /do"
```

I get

```
' example of what i want to /do'
```

How can I use one regex and remove all the phrases and //, irrespective of the number of // in a phrase?

Comment: I see one, two, and three forward slashes.  What do each of this mean here?

Comment: This is some text that I have as a result of webscraping. I want to clean the text from phrases and small sentences that do not add to the content. All the phrases that are within the slices and the slices themselves are just white noise for the algorithm I want to run.

Comment: What is the exact output that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, you can omit this part `re.search("/.*/",txt1, re.VERBOSE)` as is executes the command, but you are not doing anything with the result.

You can match 1 or more `/` followed by word chars:

```
/+\w+
```

Or a bit broader match, matching one or more `/` followed by all chars other than `/` or a whitspace chars:

```
/+[^\s/]+
```

- `/+` Match 1+ occurrences of `/`
- `[^\s/]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except a whitespace char or `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rx0mLv/1)

```
import re

strings = [
    "/this/is//an example of what I want /to///do",
    "/this/is//an example of what i want to /do"
]

for txt in strings:    
    pattern1 = r"/+[^\s/]+"
    a = re.sub(pattern1, "", txt)
    print(a)
```

Output

```
 example of what I want 
 example of what i want to
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
/(?:[^/\s]*/)*\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SBb3xK/1). *Details*:

- `/` - a slash
- `(?:[^/\s]*/)*` - zero or more repetitions of any char other than a slash and whitespace
- `\w+` - one or more word chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YvVpy1#stdout):

```py
import re
rx = re.compile(r"/(?:[^/\s]*/)*\w+")
texts = ["/this/is//an example of what I want /to///do", "/this/is//an example of what i want to /do"]
for text in texts:
    print( rx.sub('', text).strip() ) 
# => example of what I want
#    example of what i want to
```